# How to create view data from model in basic PHP MVC System

Tags: php, oop, variables, model-view-controller

I'm creating a simple PHP MVC system based on the "original" MVC principle, that is...

- Controller instructs the model based on user input / queries and loads view
- Model is a data layer is is unaware and independant from the controller or view
- View creates own copy of data from Model for presentaion purposes

Everything I've done so far conforms to these principles, however, I've stumbled upon a problem as follows...

- I set a default page title in the parent model
- I inform the model to change its page title value using a model method based on the user page request in the correct controller method (index_controller/index)
- I make a copy of models page title in the home view to b used on the template.

The problem is, the page title isnt updated because im setting the view variable in the index view constructor which happens before the model can be updated by the controller.

I can get the correct view variable by fetching and assigning it just before load the template, but the template loading is done in the parent view class which is an issue because different views require different variables.

Please let me know what I'm doing wrong! Any help is much appreciated!

It might help to see some of thecode in question...

lib/bootstrap.php

```
class Bootstrap {

    function __construct() {

        // Gets the request URL and seperate into array
        $this->url = $this->getUrlArray();

        // Generates the controller name based on URL array
        $this->controller_name = $this->getControllerName();

        // Loads controller file and creates new controller object
        $this->controller = $this->getController();

        // Calls requested methods based on URL array
        $this->callMethods();

    }

    function getUrlArray() {

        $url = isset($_GET['url']) ? rtrim($_GET['url'], '/') : 'index';
        $url = explode('/', $url);
        return $url;

    }

    function getControllerName() {

        return $this->url[0] . '_controller';

    }

    function getController() {

        $file = 'controllers/' . $this->controller_name . '.php';
        if(file_exists($file)) {
            require $file;
            return new $this->controller_name($this->url[0]);
        } else {
            require 'controllers/error_controller.php';
            return new Error_Controller('error');
        }

    }

    function callMethods() {

        if(!isset($this->url[1])) {

            $this->controller->index();

        } else {

            $method_name = $this->url[1];

            if(method_exists($this->controller, $method_name)) {

                if(!isset($this->url[2])) {

                    $this->controller->$method_name();

                } else {

                    $this->controller->$method_name($this->url[2]);

                }

            } else {

                $this->controller->index();

            }

        } 

    }

}
```

lib/controller.php

```
class Controller {

    protected $model;


    public function __construct($name) {

        $this->base_name = $name;

        $this->model_name = $this->getModelName();
        $this->model = $this->getModel();

        $this->view_name = $this->getViewName();
        $this->view = $this->getView();

        //$this->creatView();

    }

    public function getModelName() {

        return $this->base_name . '_model';

    }

    public function getViewName() {

        return $this->base_name . '_view';

    }

    public function getModel() {

        $file = 'models/' . $this->model_name . '.php';
        if(file_exists($file)) {
            require $file;
            return new $this->model_name();
        } else {
            die('ERROR: This page is missing a model!');
        }

    }

    public function getView() {

        $file = 'views/' . $this->view_name . '.php';
        if(file_exists($file)) {
            require $file;
            return new $this->view_name($this->model);
        } else {
            die('ERROR: This page is missing a view!');
        }

    }

}
```

lib/model.php

```
class Model {

    public function __construct() {

        $this->page_title = SITE_NAME;

    }

    public function setPageTitle($pre, $seperator) {

        $this->page_title = $pre . ' ' . $seperator . ' ' . SITE_NAME;

    }    

}
```

lib/view.php

```
class View {

    protected $model;

    public function __construct(Model $model) {

        $this->model = $model;

    }

    public function output($name, $noInclude = false) {

        $file = 'templates/' . $name . '.php';
        if(file_exists($file)) {

            if($noInclude) {
                require 'templates/' . $name . '.php';
            } else {
                require 'templates/header.php';
                require 'templates/' . $name . '.php';
                require 'templates/footer.php';
            }

        } else {
            die('ERROR: This page is missing a template!');
        }

    }

}
```

controllers/index_controller.php

```
<?php

class Index_Controller extends Controller {

    function __construct($name) {

        parent::__construct($name);

    }

    function index() {

        $this->model->setPageTitle('Home', '-');

        var_dump($this);

        $this->view->output('index/index');

    }

    function test($value = 'not set') {

        echo 'You are in test and the value is ' . $value;

    }

}
```

views/index_view.php

```
class Index_View extends View {

    public function __construct(Model $model) {

        parent::__construct($model);

        $this->page_title = $this->model->page_title;

    }

}
```

models/index_model.php

```
class Index_Model extends Model {

    public function __construct() {

        parent::__construct();

    }

}
```

templates/header.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title><?php echo $this->page_title; ?></title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="header">
            <!-- -->
        </div>

        <div id="content">
```

[My var_dump in index_controller looks like this...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hvqvq.png)

Cheers,
Tom

Comment: I'm still intrigued with your code, but I'll ask questions here until I find an answer that won't get a stupid drive-by down-vote.  I missed the "original" MVC interpretation and was trying to be practical.  Sorry about that.

Comment: That being said, what pops out at me is that your view gets all its data from the model, so wouldn't it make sense to use the model's data as in `<title><?= $this->model->page_title; ?></title>`?

Comment: or, you could pass it by reference `$this->page_title = &$this->model->page_title;`